# Allow HTML in Settings API input field

Tags: html, settings-api, escaping, input

I want to allow HTML into a plugin input field via a user, I am using the Settings API, but it strips everything HTML out. - Code below  -any pointers?

```
function plugin_settings(){
  register_Setting(
        'ng_settings_group', 
        'my_settings',
        'plugin_prefix validate_input' 
  );
  add_settings_section(
        'my_section', 
        'My Settings', 
        'plugin_prefix my_section_callback', 
        'plugin'
    );
   add_settings_field(
        'ng_menu_html',
        'HTML Carat', 
        'plugin_prefix ng_html_callback', 
        'plugin', 
        'my_section' 
    );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_prefix plugin_settings');

function ng_html_callback() {
$options = get_option( 'my_settings' ); 

if( !isset( $options['ng_html'] ) ) $options['ng_html'] = '';

echo '<label for="ng_html">' . esc_attr_e( 'Insert additional HTML','plugin') . '</label>';
echo '<input type="text" id="ng_html" name="my_settings[ng_html]" value="' . $options['ng_html'] . '" placeholder="Add HTML">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you register a setting, you pass the santize callback for that setting:

```
register_setting(
    'my_setting_group', 
    'my_setting_name',
     // The next parameter is the validation callback
    'my_setting_validation' 
);
```

Then, in the validation callback you can allow whatever you want. For example, in the next code snippet, users with `unfiltered_html` capability will be allowed to insert raw HTML code; other users are allowed to insert the same HTML tags allowed in post content:

```
function my_setting_validation( $input ) {

    // Check for the field that we want to allow html
    if( $input['ng_menu_html'] ) {

        if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') ) {

            $validated_input['ng_menu_html'] =  $input['ng_menu_html'];

        } else {

            $validated_input['ng_menu_html'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( wp_slash( $input['ng_menu_html'] ) ) ); // wp_filter_post_kses() expects slashed


        }


     } else {

         // Sanitize here other fields with no HTML or whatever you want

     }

     return $validated_input;

 }
```

Finally, you need to use `esc_attr()` when set the value of the field:

```
function ng_html_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'my_setting_name' ); 

    if( !isset( $options['ng_html'] ) ) $options['ng_html'] = '';

        echo '<label for="ng_html">' . _e( 'Insert additional HTML', 'plugin') . '</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="ng_html" name="my_settings[ng_html]" value="' . esc_attr( $options['ng_html'] ) . '" placeholder="Add HTML">';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks cybmeta that works great - for the other input fields which require no HTML what is best to add in the else field.

`else {

         // Sanitize here other fields with no HTML or whatever you want

     }
`
I have tried a few but the settings are not being saved.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with for the validation - partly taken from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-7-validation-sanitisation-and-input-i--wp-25289)

```
function my_setting_validation( $input ) {
       // Create our array for storing the validated options
        $output = array();

        // Loop through each of the incoming options
        foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {

            if( isset( $input['ng_menu_html'] ) ) {

                // Keep HTML in this field
               $output['ng_menu_html'] = wp_kses_post($input['ng_menu_html']);

            } // end if

            // Check to see if the current option has a value. If so, process it.
            if( isset( $input[$key] ) ) {

                // Strip all HTML and PHP tags and properly handle quoted strings
                $output[$key] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $input[ $key ] ) );

            } // end if


        } // end foreach

        // Return the array processing any additional functions filtered by this action
        return apply_filters( 'my_setting_validation' , $output, $input );
    }
```

And as you pointed out ensure `esc_attr` is used in the input field.

```
echo '<input type="text" id="ng_menu_html" name="my_settings[ng_menu_html]" value="' . esc_attr($options['ng_menu_html']) . '" placeholder="Add custom HTML mark up">';
```